# Realm Migration Duplicated values

Tags: java, database, realm

i want to do a Migration(Realm 87.2) i did others before, but this one is not easy and i dont know why

my previsoly Categoriy.class

```
private int code;
private String title;
private String category;
private int order;
private boolean visible;
```

**the new Category.class**

```
@PrimaryKey @Index private String id;
    private int code;
    private String title;
    private String category;
    private int order;
    private boolean visible;
```

and at the Migration.class

```
public class Migration....
int i = 0;
.....
  if(oldVersion == 7) {
            schema.get("Category").addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY).transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
                @Override
                public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                    obj.set("id", UtilsForAll.getRandomUUID()); //Get Random UUID for previsoly added categories
                    obj.set("order", i);
                    i++;
                }
            });
oldVersion++;

}
} //finishClass
```

for some dumb reason and i dont know what im doing wrong, it keep giving me this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Argument: Field "id"
>   cannot be a primary key, it already contains duplicate values:

WHAT? there are no duplicate values at categorie class, im pretty sure.

PS: this just happens when i really use the Migration and HAS PREVIOSLY CATEGORY RECORDS

--------------------- EDIT 22/03

tried this as Emanuelez`s suggestion:

```
  if(oldVersion == 7) {
schema.get("Category").addField("id", String.class);
                schema.get("Category").transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                        obj.set("id", UtilsForAll.getRandomUUID()); //Get Random UUID for previsoly added categories

                    }
                });
    oldVersion++;

schema.get("Category").setPrimaryKey("id");
    }
```

the error turned into this one -

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field 'id' does
>   support null values in the existing Realm file. Remove @Required or
>   @PrimaryKey from field 'id' or migrate using
>   io.realm.internal.Table.convertColumnToNotNullable().

i`ve tried`.setNullable("id", true);`

nothing changed too

Answer (score 3):

To add a new primary key field you cannot just add a field with the attribute since all those fields will be initialized to their default value, being all equal, which breaks the primary key contract.

To do this the right way you have to:

1. create a new field
2. populate the new field with new distinct values
3. make the new field a primary key

For further reference I suggest you to take a look at the unit tests for the RealmObjectSchema class, which can be found [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/androidTest/java/io/realm/RealmObjectSchemaTests.java)

Comment: tried this 3 steps, nothing changed, just the error, and i think im doing exactly the same thing as the test you pointed me =(